# why does object turn to int after one use

Tags: python, class, oop

I am learning python and while going through this OOP'S exercise:

For this challenge, create a bank account class that has two attributes:
owner
balance
and two methods:
deposit
withdraw
As an added requirement, withdrawals may not exceed the available balance.

Now the problem that I am facing is when I run the withdrawal once it works fine, but when I work it the second time it shows the error

" TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
/var/folders/15/yqw5v0lx20q5lrbvg8bb69jr0000gn/T/ipykernel_79159/1232198771.py in 
----> 1 acct1.withdraw(200)

TypeError: 'int' object is not callable"

here is my code

```
class Account:
def __init__(self, owner, balance = 0):
        self.owner = owner
        self.balance = balance
def __str__(self):
    return f"the account holder is {self.owner} \nand the balance is {self.balance}"
        
def deposit(self,deposit):
    self.deposit = deposit
    self.balance += deposit
    print("deposit accepted")

def withdraw(self, withdraw):
    self.withdraw = withdraw
    if self.balance >= withdraw:
        self.balance -= withdraw
        print("money withdrawn")
    else:
        print("Funds Unavailable!")
```

Kindly let me know where am I going wrong.

Comment: Please supply the code that results in the error.

Comment: You have method and field collision: `def withdraw(self, withdraw)` and `self.withdraw = withdraw`

Comment: why do you do this `self.deposit = deposit`?  and `self.withdraw = withdraw` ...these lines seem unnecessary, and are also causing the problem as noted by @JacobIRR

Comment: Does this code work? As presented, it gave me an indentation error. After correcting that, it needs to fix suggested in the answers.

Comment: How do you run this code?

Answer (score 1):

Do not name a method the same as a class attribute:

```
def withdraw(self, withdraw):
    self.withdraw = withdraw
```

Possible solution:

```
def perform_withdraw(self, withdraw):
    self.withdraw = withdraw
```

Answer (score 1):

Before the first call to `withdraw`, the attribute `withdraw` of an instance of `Account` is the method that does your calculation.

After the first call to `withdraw`, the attribute is whatever argument you called `withdraw` with, because you issue `self.withdraw = withdraw`. Use another name or remove the line altogether if it is not needed.